# Add Column X rows, if Column Y rows match

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have two columns: countryCode, blockCount:

```
+-------------+------------+
| countryCode | blockCount |
+-------------+------------+
| CN          |          4 |
| US          |          1 |
| TR          |          3 |
| HK          |          1 |
| US          |          2 |
+-------------+------------+
```

I want to combine any matching rows in countryCode, and add their blockCounts together.

For example, "US" would become a single row, with a blockCount of 3.

Tried a while loop, failed miserably.

**EDIT:** GROUP BY is not working

Comment: Hint: use a `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: I tried that first, returns all 1s for blockCount. Query: SELECT blockCount, countryCode FROM wp_wfblockediplog GROUP BY countryCode;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there. But each column not in the `GROUP BY` clause must be given to an aggregation function (alas, in poorly configured or older version of MySQL this rule isn't enforced but somewhat unpredictable results are produced instead). Here you want `sum()` that sums the values in the group.

```
SELECT sum(blockcount),
       countrycode
       FROM wp_wfblockediplog
       GROUP BY countrycode;
```